# Is there an elegant way to parametrize Sass bundling per page in npm?

Tags: css, npm, sass, bundle, build-automation

What I'd like to achieve is an elegant way to have a page->sass files mapping that would run sass compilation, create a special css bundle and put a link to it to the page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I am right, you want that the files (with extension sccs/sass) from some folder let called "SASS" be compiled automatically and saved to another folder let called "CSS".

Then, you can use "npm sass" if you are working with react and if you're using with plain HTML you can install "watch sass" extension available in vs code and atom, I don't know about other editors.